# Creating an onclick event to append a string in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, onclick

My school has a punctuality spreadsheet (excel) which is filled in by the head of achievement.To identify how many lessons they have been late each day they append the appropriate number of X's to the cell.

This of course requires selecting the cell, double clicking, adding the X then moving onto the next of student... typically they can enter over 200 entries a day which is rather time consuming.

I'd like to write an on-click event so that when the user clicks (or double clicks) a cell in a given range it automatically appends an X to that cells string.

Over a week this will save a ridiculous amount if time if it is possible.

I have to admit I'm not certain how to start this in Excel, though I am competent with VB.NET and VBA for ACCESS.

I know this could be accomplished with around 1000 macro buttons but there must be a better way.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open VBA editor, Alt + F11.

Doubleclick on the sheet you want this function on in the window to the left.

Copy paste:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Target.Value = "x" ' if you want to replace the value in the cell with x
    Target.value = Target.Value & "x" ' if you want to add one x to the value of the cell

End Sub
```

Delete the row you do not find correct for your needs.

Close VBA editor and save file as macroactivated excel file (xlsm).

Comment: All thought this answer gets you started I would like to point out that the `Target.Value = "X"` should actually be `Target.Value = Target.Value & "X"` if you want to **append** that X.

Comment: Do you think his question is to append? Meaning `xx` in one cell? Reading the question it seems as there is columns with students and rows with lessons. Having two x on one row sound odd. But you are correct. If the user wants to append, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I think so, what the op says _"append the appropriate number of X's to the cell"_ refers that he want to put multiple X's to one cell.. But figures, could be just a typo..

Comment: @SickDimension Now that I think of it... You may be correct. Why else would you doubleclick on the cell? Single click is to "replace", and the OP says doubleclick several times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

Open VBA (Alt + F11)

Open the sheet you want this function to work in from the window on the left.

Then paste:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5")) Is Nothing Then _
  Range("B5") = "X"
End Sub
```

You can control the range by changing "B5". Currently it only adds the "X" when you click on B5.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be use a Macro with a ShortCut key

[image]
    Sub AddX()

```
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then

        If ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & "X"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```